# Drupal cant find search_api namespace

Tags: 8

I know i need to use the following imports for a custom module i copied from another Drupal installation.

```
use Drupal\search_api\Entity\Index;
use Drupal\search_api\Query\Query;
use Drupal\search_api\Query\QueryInterface;
```

But phpstorm tells me Entity and Query can't be found, so i assume its the `Drupal/search_api` it doesn't find. How can i import them anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the search_api is a different module than i thought. 
Just install it with composer like this:

```
composer require drupal/search_api
```